# IE9 doesn't display content unless F12 is enabled. Could it be caching?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, ie-developer-tools

I have a scenario where content is not displayed on W7/IE9 unless I have the F12 development environment open/enabled. I don't have that problem on other browsers (FF, Chrome).

I monitored the traffic not using F12 output, and I do see the response with the content payload.
Nothing gets displayed. I hit the browser's refresh button and nothing occurs. I turn on F12 and hit refresh and the content displays.

I saw [IE9 makes ajax call correctly only ofter hitting F12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147553/ie9-makes-ajax-call-correctly-only-ofter-hitting-f12)
but I don't have any console.log calls in the JavaScript.

Comment: See also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147553/ie9-makes-ajax-call-correctly-only-ofter-hitting-f12

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the nature of the problem was a lingering call to console.log.
By removing the call, it behaved as expected.