# This code works in all other browsers except in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works fine in all browsers except IE can anyone explain why so I can fix it. I am displaying the index of a javascript object based on the index of the selected index of my dropdown list

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
var pdata = [{ Name: "Apples", Price: 1.99 },{ Name: "Bananas", Price: 2.45 } ];

    $('#produceTMPL').tmpl(pdata).appendTo('#produceList');

      $(document).ready(function () {


      $('#add1').click(function () {
        var selected = $('#produceList option:selected').index();

        item = pdata[selected];

        console.log(selected);
        $('#cart').append('<p>' + item.Name + ', ' + item.Price + '</p>');




    });  
    });
```

HTML:

```
     <div>
  <select id="produceList">
  <option>make a selection</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Did you open the web developer console? F12

Comment: How does this "not work" in IE?  Which version of IE?  What *does* it do?  Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Why do you have a `$(document).ready(function () {` inside of a `$(document).ready(function () {`?

Comment: do you really need 2 document ready calls there? Also, older versions of IE will probably cry if you try to run console

Comment: Try to open the console, then reload your page and see if it works.  `console.log` won't work in IE unless the console is open.

Comment: @KaiQing: Good call!  Forgot IE did that.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11147595/1363726

Comment: @ Rocket Hazmat I removed the console.log and removed the extra $(document).ready(function(){}); but it still says undefined in my html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a protected property of the  window object in IE. Just rename your variable, or declare it properly (using `var`) in your function.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` throws an error in IE, so to be on the safer side DO NOT use console.log with out checking if browser supports it or not.

```
try{
    if(console && console.log) console.log('message')   
}catch(e){}
```

OR

```
 if ('undefined' !== typeof console){console.log(message); }
```

Comment: IE supports `console.log`.  The console (dev tools) just need to be opened for it to do so.  You need to open the dev tools, then reload your page.

Comment: That's why I suggested to open it then reload the page.

Comment: but in IE it says undefined on my html

Comment: @RocketHazmat I know, but what I am trying to say is no body has it open in the first, at which time, console.log is not supported, and if u want to avoid that situation, check before blindly using the function.

Comment: @Rao: Fair enough :-)

Comment: @ Rocket Hazmat I removed the console.log and removed the extra $(document).ready(function(){}); but it still says undefined in my html – chrisp54

Comment: try renaming `item`, as suggested by Teemu